# FormView to populate from selection on GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formview

I have a DropDownList that populates a GridView according to the selected value. I then have a FormView that I want to populate with data depending on what field was selected out of the DataGrid.

My GridView has DataKeyNames="ID", and I then use the following to update the selected field:

`<ItemTemplate>
                                <a href="#" onclick="addEdit(<%# Eval("ID") %>)">Update</a>
                            </ItemTemplate>`

My FormView's ObjectDataSource uses the following:

`<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="grvMain" Name="pID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                Type="Int32" />`

I still can't seem to get the FormView populated with the correct data, or any data at all for that matter, when user clicks on Update in the grid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to look into {Binding} or add using HTMLControls to your using and gaining access to that variable via jscript or code behind..? what does addEditMethod look like is that javascript..?

Comment: It doesn't really do much...It sets a div's visibility...If I can use that method to populate the formview with the pID I send through, then I'd do that but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: tell you what.. Melanie can you paste an example of what you have and we can try to help you from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following, to the gridview

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
```

Should create a select button.